# 14 questions tagged superuser

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

And some of these aren't even meta questions... I'd retag them all myself, but I don't want to fill the front page with old questions. [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/superuser)

Comment: The fact is that superuser actually means something, for some of these questions.

Answer (score 4):

> Maybe go with [root] instead of [superuser] for the *nix ones, and [administrator] for the Windows ones?

I think this suggestion by Hello71 makes a lot of sense, particularly since as Hyperslug said..

> Serverfault itself does not use a [superuser] tag

Answer (score 3):

Deleted all those that were Meta related.

Since there are only seven left, go ahead and retag them.

It'll be a minor flooding on the front page, but it'll be quick.

They do look like they're valid uses of the **`[superuser]`** tag though.

Comment: Maybe go with `[root]` instead of `[superuser]` for the *nix ones, and `[administrator]` for the Windows ones?

Comment: Tough call.  It's a confusing term for our site, but superuser is a valid term for a [generic administrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser).  It's worth noting that Serverfault itself does not use a **`[superuser]`** tag.  Maybe escalate this to [Washington](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @hyperslug: It's still only about SU, not the SE/SO engine.